# Converting VB to C# - error "invalid SimpleNonInvocationExpression"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharpdevelop, code-conversion, vb.net-to-c#

I am using SharpDevelop 4.4 to convert some VB.NET to C# code. It produced the following error which I don't understand:

```
D:\path\ClassName.vb is not converted:
Parser found 1 error(s)
-- line 143 col 22: invalid SimpleNonInvocationExpression
```

The line of code it complains about is:

```
result = -10 ^ -5 * x ^ 2 + 0.0004 * x + 8.3463
```

where `x` is a `Single`. Column 22 is the leading minus sign.

The VB code compiles fine... what does this error message mean?

---

Searching on "SimpleNonInvocationExpression" the only things I can find are source code to SharpDevelop or websites which are not in English that I can't read.

---

EDIT: As a workaround I commented the line out, converted the code, and then manually translated the line. This was a fine workaround for a single line, but would be a disaster for many.

The end result (as suggested by @topshot) was:

```
result = -Math.Pow(10, -5) * Math.Pow(x, 2) + 0.0004 * x + 8.3463;
```

Comment: Presumably the people to ask would be sharpdevelop tech support, since you seem to have found a bug in their product.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks Eric, it wasn't immediately obvious to me that this was a bug.

Comment: I'd try to adding parentheses around the exponentiation, and run the converter again. Or rewrite it to C# yourself. I think the meaning of this expression is `c * x * x` where `c = -1.0E-5` in [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)

Comment: My advice would be to work around the bug by changing the code to read `-0.00001 * x * x + 0.0004 * x + 8.3463`; maybe the problem is that it is getting confused by the `^` operator, which does not exist in C# as the power operator. (In C#, `^` is the XOR operator.)

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but is `result` an explicitly declared variable in the VB source or is the code compiled with `Option Explicit Off`.

Comment: [Telerik's converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) gives this `result = -Math.Pow(10, -5) * Math.Pow(x, 2) + 0.0004 * x + 8.3463;`

Comment: @EricLippert I tried that but it produced the same error, thanks for the idea.

Comment: @topshot thanks, I ended up just converting this line manually and that was pretty similar to what I used.